# Sorting image name files in Matlab?

Tags: string, image, matlab

I have two different types of dicom(medical imaging files) in the same folder. I want to sort them into two different arrays one for the SE006 and the other for the SE014.

```
    MR-ST001-SE006-0001.dcm... MR-ST001-SE006-0021.dcm  
    MR-ST001-SE014-0001.dcm... MR-ST001-SE014-0013.dcm
```

I have been using something like this code below but it is wrong I think I have some syntax errors.

```
  if image == 'MR-ST001-SE006-%4.4.dcm'
      SE006(end+1) = image 
  if image == 'MR-ST001-SE014-%4.4.dcm'
      SE014(end+1) = image
```

Anyone have any tips to help improve this so it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read all the files into a cell array with [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) command and then use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to vectorize the solution from  @jonsca.

```
files = dir('MR-ST001-SE*.dcm');
dcmnames = {files(:).name}';
idx06 = ~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(dcmnames,'SE006'));
idx14 = ~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(dcmnames,'SE014'));
SE006 = dcmnames(idx06);
SE014 = dcmnames(idx14);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of [strfind()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) and [isempty()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isempty.html) with an `if/else if` block should sort them.

```
 if ~isempty(strfind(yourstr,'SE006'))
     #add it to your list
 end
```